# L'Hopitals Rule - Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Part A:**

Let $a_n=\gamma ^{s \over n}$ for some $\gamma>1$, some $s>0$, and all positive integers $n$. Show that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$$

I've got this part, super easy.

**Part B:**

Fix some s>0. Determine (with proof!)

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\gamma^{s/n}-1\over\gamma^{1/n}-1}$$

Here's where I'm having problems!  It's clear that using L'Hopitial's Rule will give me the answer I want, but the Theorem we are given says three things:

1) $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be continuous on $[a,b]$

2) $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be differentiable on $(a,b)$

3) For some $c \in [a,b], f(c)=g(c)=0$

My problem is two fold:

- The first is that I have a function that is defined across an open interval and my Theorem applies to closed intervals.
- The second is that, currently, I do not have a $c$ where $f(c)=g(c)=0$.  I contemplated doing a substitution where $x=\gamma^{1\over n}$, but that requires me to change the limit from $n \to \infty$ to $x\to ?$.  I don't know what I can change the limit to.  Making $x \to 1$ is the obvious answer, but how do I justify it?

Comment: The hypotheses in L'Hopital's Rule apply to the variable for which the limit is being taken.

Comment: $f(\gamma)=\gamma^{\frac{s}{n}}-1$, $g(\gamma)=\gamma^{\frac{1}{n}}-1$ and $c=1$ ;)

Comment: @Jonathan: Please don't delete the body of your question, even after you've had it answered.  That just confuses other users of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following limit
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{a^x-1}{x}}=\ln{a}$$
we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\dfrac{\gamma^{\tfrac{s}{n}}-1}{\gamma^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left({\dfrac{\gamma^{\tfrac{s}{n}}-1}{\frac{s}{n}}}\cdot {\dfrac{{\frac{s}{n}}}{\gamma^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1}}\right)=s\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left({\dfrac{\gamma^{\tfrac{s}{n}}-1}{\frac{s}{n}}}\cdot {\dfrac{{\frac{1}{n}}}{\gamma^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1}}\right)=\\
=s\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\dfrac{\gamma^{\tfrac{s}{n}}-1}{\frac{s}{n}}} \cdot \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\dfrac{{\frac{1}{n}}}{\gamma^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1}}= s\dfrac{\ln{\gamma}}{\ln{\gamma}}=s.$$